# looking for better solution to moving a button based on window size, using react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, media-queries

I have a small button with a position that I want to move based on the window width. There is an upper bound (how far right) and a lower bound (how far left) that this button can shift. I currently have a solution to this, but the performance on the webpage is not optimal. There is a slight lag to the button moving.
My current solution sets an initial state for the position of the button. I added an eventListener to the componentDidMount method to detect a change in window size. When the size changes it calls the following method:

```
updateButtonLocation() {
        if(window.innerWidth>=1260) {
            this.setState({editButtonLocation:1218});
        }
        else if(window.innerWidth<1260 && window.innerWidth>762){
            this.setState({editButtonLocation:window.innerWidth-42});
        }
        else {
            this.setState({editButtonLocation: 720});
        }
    }
```

The following css code then positions the button where I need it to be:

```
style={props.isShowBtn?{display:"inline", left: props.editButtonLocation}:{display:'none'}}
```

There were two other solutions that might be better. Instead of using state, I can do the following for the style:

```
style={props.isShowBtn?{display:"inline", left: 90vw}:{display:'none'}}
```

This moves the button with window size, however I dont think i can set the upper and lower bounds. If this is possible, how do I do it?

The other option I am looking into is using media query. I have no experience with this technology, however. Is it possible to use this tool to do what my above code does?

Comment: This would be much better handled via css media queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
button {
    position: relative;
    left: 720px;
}
@media (min-width: 1260px) {
    button {
       left: 1218px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1260px) and (min-width: 762px) {
    button {
        left: calc(100vw - 42px);
    }
}
```

Yes, It's possible by using media queries. You can't use properties like top and left without setting the position of a element. You might wanna use margin in this case.

Comment: Thank you, This was a much better and cleaner solution